# Pandas MultiIndex change order of one level ONLY

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multiindex columns:

```
 |A    |B
 |1 |2 |1 |2
0|a  b  c  d
```

I would like to swap level one to get:

```
 |A    |B
 |2 |1 |2 |1
0|b |a |d |c
```

But with

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

I get:

```
 |A|B|A|B
 |1|1|2|2
0|a|c|b|d
```

Please help

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry messed up there. Should have been df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1, ascending=False) and the result I don't like is b d a c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming they have the same label, you can use `reindex` with `level=1`:

```
df

   A     B   
   1  2  1  2
0  a  b  c  d

df.reindex([2, 1], level=1, axis=1)

   A     B   
   2  1  2  1
0  b  a  d  c
```

To generalise, you can access `MultiIndex.levels`:

```
df.reindex(df.columns.levels[1][::-1], level=1, axis=1)

   A     B   
   2  1  2  1
0  b  a  d  c
```

---

If the second level values are not the same for all first level labels, use

```
df.loc[:, ::-1].reindex(df.columns.levels[0], level=0, axis=1)

   A     B   
   2  1  2  1
0  b  a  d  c
```

Answer (score 3):

You still can using `sort_index`

```
df.sort_index(level=[0,1],ascending=[True,False],axis=1)
   A     B   
   2  1  2  1
0  b  a  d  c
```

Comment: While this works, it's not the same. You still sort the first level. The only thing is that doesn't matter here.

Comment: I think this one is more clear on what is intended. Very pythonic

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, [2, 1]]]
```

?